# Non-relational database modeling tool?

Tags: data-warehouse, non-relational-database, database-design

Hey guys, please recommend some tools you have used succesfully on DW, DataMart, BI an non-relational modeling.
Example for automatic creation of snow-flake Schemas, dimensions and facts tables.
Wich tools makes you sense familiarity with the diagrams and surrogates keys and it will have the option for export or connect to SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Powerdesigner from Sybase. Have used it to do a DW for a Central Bank.  Very powerful can layer, i.e. Link dims and facts back to a relational model. Downside is $$$.